# How to read EXCEL file data to json using node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, node-modules

How to read EXCEL file data to json using node.js

path of the folder is outside the server 
ie,

any where in computer eg. dev/public/uploads

Please help me..

```
exceltojson({
  input:'D:/uploads/ab.xlsx',
  output: "test.json",
  sheet: "Sheet1",  // specific sheet name inside excel file 
  lowerCaseHeaders:true 
 }, function(err, result) {
if(err) {
  console.error(err);
} else {
 }  });
```

ab.xlsx file is placed on D: drive of the computer

Comment: any one is there..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can convert an Excel file to CSV, then read it as an old plain text file and create an object which will be serialized to JSON.
2. Recent versions of Excel file format are simple XML files, not some strange binary format. You can read this XML and serialize it to JSON.
3. You can try different npm libraries, which accomplish this task, for example, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-to-json).

Comment: Jehy, I am use excel-to-json module in node.js. but path specification is wrong.. what should i do.

Comment: 1. Input and output should be directories. 2. Please post all code, I think that you are missing requires or smth like this.

Comment: Actually I mean that, how to read the excel file from a specified path outside of the application directory using node.js i am using moduls like xls-to-json-lc .. how to specified the path of the file. file is located D directory,which is outside of the application directory.